# Undefine variable user, user being passed in method from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm passing in the user instance through route model binding, and I'm attempting to use the user in a query.

This is the function and the query.

```php
public function text(User $user)
{

    $messages = DB::table('messages')
    ->join('threads', function($join){
        $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
        ->where('threads.id', '=', $user->threads[0]->id);
    })->get();

    return view('backend.pending_registrations.textform', compact('user', 'messages'));

}
```

I'm getting this error

> Undefined variable: user

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you need to pass `$user` into your closure.

```
->join('threads', function($join) use ($user) {
    $join->on('messages.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
        ->where('threads.id', '=', $user->threads[0]->id);
})->get();
```